# .Rd file generation in a package using Rcpp

Tags: r, rstudio, rcpp

I created a test package containing `Rcpp` code using `Rcpp.package.skeleton()` command. All the required files as per vignette were generated and I was able to compile the package.

I tried to add `roxygen2` style comments to the example code

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

//' @param none required
//' @return List of functions
// [[Rcpp::export]]
List rcpp_hello_world() {

    CharacterVector x = CharacterVector::create( "foo", "bar" )  ;
    NumericVector y   = NumericVector::create( 0.0, 1.0 ) ;
    List z            = List::create( x, y ) ;

    return z ;
}
```

I see that the new `R/RcppExports.R` shows the modifications

```
#' @param none required
#' @return List of functions
rcpp_hello_world <- function() {
    .Call('TestPackageRcpp_rcpp_hello_world', PACKAGE = 'TestPackageRcpp')
}
```

but these changes do not get transferred to the `rcpp_hello_world.Rd` file and the `?rcpp_hello_world()` still gives

```
rcpp_hello_world {TestPackageRcpp}  R Documentation
Simple function using Rcpp

Description

Simple function using Rcpp

Usage

rcpp_hello_world()  
Examples

## Not run: 
rcpp_hello_world()

## End(Not run)
```

Similarly, I created another file `timesTwo.cpp` file and added the

```
//' @param - a numeric vector
//' @return - a numeric vector
```

to the `timesTwo.cpp` file. I see the modifications in the `R/RcppExports.R` file

```
#' @param numeric vector
#' @return numeric vector
timesTwo <- function(x) {
    .Call('TestPackageRcpp_timesTwo', PACKAGE = 'TestPackageRcpp', x)
}
```

but no new `/man/timesTwo.Rd` file is created.

I also run `Rcpp::compileAttributes()` after creating the new file and run Build and Reload the package.

Am I creating new files in a wrong way? It's not a big issue and I can write the `timesTwo.Rd` manually, but I want to be able to write comments in `timesTwo.cpp` if the functionality is available already. I am using

```
platform       x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0   
arch           x86_64                      
os             darwin13.1.0                
system         x86_64, darwin13.1.0        
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          1.0                         
year           2014                        
month          04                          
day            10                          
svn rev        65387                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
nickname       Spring Dance
```

and `Rcpp` version `0.11.6` and `RStudio` version `0.99.441`

Comment: You'll have to call `devtools::document()` to ensure `.Rd` files are created from the roxygen comments generated.

Comment: Thanks! See my comment below for the full response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know *if* you use RStudio all this is done for you -- because RStudio very much supports tboth roxygen2 and of course Rcpp.  You may have to ensure you click a box in the RStudio Tools configuration to use roxygen.

I still do it by hand, or rather, shell script.  The sad part is that we (currently at least) do not have "hooks" in the `R CMD build` step to automate this.

So when I update a `.cpp` source file, I typically invoke a script [`compAttr.r`](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/littler/blob/master/examples/compAttr.r) to invoke the `compileAttributes()` function from Rcpp. I will take the roxygen markup from the .cpp to the .R file.

I then invoke a script [`roxy.r`](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/littler/blob/master/examples/roxy.r) to generate (or update) the .Rd file from the .R file.  by my choice, this only updates the .Rd file and leaves `DESCRIPTION` and `NAMESPACE` alone.

Both these scripts are part of [littler](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html) and I make sure they are on my `$PATH`.

Comment: Thanks @DirkEddelbuettel  and Kevin Ushey. It was a matter of checking the boxes in Project Tools - 'Generate documentation with Roxygen' and 'Automatically reoxygenize when running Build & Reload'. However, I noticed just adding `@param` and `@return` gives me an error `Error : ~/TestPackageRcpp/man/timesTwo.Rd: Sections \title, and \name must exist and be unique in Rd files`. So I also had to add `@name` and `@title` to the new file `timesTwo.cpp`.